# Drawing multiple object with texture doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm working on a 3D model loader. It can loads my own format. I wrote my own exporter for Blender, it works well. The model format can handle multiple meshes(objects) in one model. Each mesh can have a different texture. I've already written a loader which is working well, but doesn't use shaders.

I switched to shaders, but something is going wrong, the textures aren't appear correctly. Here is my drawing function, I'm sure the mistake is somewhere here:

```
void CModel::draw(glm::mat4 &MVP)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<m_numObjects; i++)
    {
        glUseProgram(m_programID);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(m_matrixUniform, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureIDs[i]);
        glUniform1i(m_textureUniform, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_bufferIDs[i]);

        // vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
                0,                  // must match the layout in the shader.
                3,                  // size
                GL_FLOAT,           // type
                GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                sizeof(float)*8,    // stride
                (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // UVs
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
                1,
                2,
                GL_FLOAT,
                GL_FALSE,
                sizeof(float)*8,
                (void*)6
        );

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_numElements[i]);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glUseProgram(0);
    }

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

The vertex and fragment shaders are also working well.

The previous version (without shaders) was this (this worked well):

```
void CModel::draw()
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<m_numObjects; i++)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureIDs[i]);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_bufferIDs[i]);

        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(float)*8, (float*)(sizeof(float)*6));
        glNormalPointer(     GL_FLOAT, sizeof(float)*8, (float*)(sizeof(float)*3));
        glVertexPointer(  3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(float)*8, 0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_numElements[i]);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

**Here is the entire class:**

```
#include "global.h"
#include "CModel.h"
#include "CModelLoader.h"
#include "CShaderLoader.h"

CModel::CModel(){}

CModel::~CModel()
{
    // TODO free memory
}

/** @brief Load mbm file
  *
  * @fileName: mdm model file name we want to load and draw
  */
void CModel::init(char *fileName)
{
    CModelLoader   loader;
    CShaderLoader  shaders;

    loader.loadData(fileName);

    loader.createDataArray( m_dataArray,
                            m_dataArraySizes,
                            m_numObjects,
                            m_numElements,
                            m_textureIDs );

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(m_vertexArrayID);

    m_programID      = shaders.loadShaders("vertexshader.vert", "fragmentshader.frag");

    m_bufferIDs      = new unsigned int[m_numObjects];

    glGenBuffers(m_numObjects, m_bufferIDs);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<m_numObjects; i++)
    {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_bufferIDs[i]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*m_dataArraySizes[i], m_dataArray[i], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

}

/** @brief Drawing the mdm model
  *
  */
void CModel::draw(glm::mat4 &MVP)
{

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<m_numObjects; i++)
    {
        glUseProgram(m_programID);

        unsigned int matrixUniform  = glGetUniformLocation(m_programID, "MVP");
        unsigned int textureUniform = glGetUniformLocation(m_programID, "myTextureSampler");

        glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixUniform, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
        glUniform1i(textureUniform, 0);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureIDs[i]);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_bufferIDs[i]);

        // vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
                0,                  // must match the layout in the shader.
                3,                  // size
                GL_FLOAT,           // type
                GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                sizeof(float)*8,    // stride
                (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // UVs
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
                1,
                2,
                GL_FLOAT,
                GL_FALSE,
                sizeof(float)*8,
                (void*)6
        );

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_numElements[i]);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glUseProgram(0);
    }

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);



    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Comment: When and how do you determine the uniform locations? If you want to be on the safe side use glGetUniformLocation everytime after you do a glUseProgram.

Comment: Also, where are your attribute indices coming from? Where are they being set in your shader?

Comment: I put glGetUniformLocation after glUseProgram, but it doesn't work.
The indices coming from a model file, but it is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it. The problem was that I used one array for vertices, normals and texture coordinates instead of storing in separate arrays and bind them separately.